# How to downcast parent class to inherited child class in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I have the following classes:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class UserDO{
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class ReviewerDO extends UserDO{
    private String reviewerType;
}
```

So it should be possible to instantiate a user. At some point the user might be promoted to also become a more specialised user (such as a `ReviewerDO`). So the following service takes care of the promotion:

```java
    public void assignUserToReviewer(UserDO userDO) {
        ReviewerDO reviewerDO = (ReviewerDO) userDO;
        reviewerDO.setReviewerType("COMPLIANCE");
        reviewerRepository.save(reviewerDO);
    }
```

It fails because it cannot typecast a `UserDO` to a `ReviewerDO`:

> UserDO cannot be cast to Reviewer

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Casting does not automatically convert one type of object into another type of object. You'll have to create a new `RevieweDO` object and copy the field values from the original `UserDO` object into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of typecasting :

- **Upcasting** (child class to parent class & child class to child class)
- **Downcasting** (parent class to child class)

Example of the issue faced by you.

```
package com.example;

class UserDO {

    //..
}

class ReviewerDO extends UserDO {

    private String reviewerType;

    public ReviewerDO(String reviewerType) {
      this.reviewerType = reviewerType;
    }

}

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserDO user = new UserDO(); // upcast (child to child)
        /* 
         * This will throw ClassCastException as direct downcasting
         * is not possible. 
         */
        ReviewerDO reviewerDO = (ReviewerDO) user; //downcast

    }

}
```

Output :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.UserDO cannot be cast to com.example.ReviewerDO
```

**The solution can be in two ways :**

1. Indirect Downcasting.

For example :

```
package com.example;

    class UserDO {

        //..
    }

    class ReviewerDO extends UserDO {

        private String reviewerType;

        public ReviewerDO(String reviewerType) {
          this.reviewerType = reviewerType;
        }

    }

    public class Example {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            UserDO user = new ReviewerDO(); // upcast (child to parent)
            /*
             * Here downcasting happens. This doesn't throw 
             * ClassCastException.
             */
            ReviewerDO reviewerDO = (ReviewerDO) user; //downcast happens indirectly.

        }

    }
```

2. **Recommended:** Create your own helper class and create custom method to copy values of one object into another using getters and setters.

For example :

```
public void assignUserToReviewer(UserDO userDO) {
    ReviewerDO reviewerDO = Helper.createReviewerDO(userDO);
    reviewerDO.setReviewerType("COMPLIANCE");
    reviewerRepository.save(reviewerDO);
}

public final class Helper {

  public static ReviewerDO createReviewerDO(UserDO userDO) {
      ReviewerDO r = new ReviewerDO();
      r.setSomething(userDO.getSomeThing());
      ... 
      return r;
  }

}
```